# Dispatching a delayed second action with Redux-Observable while keeping the first one

Tags: javascript, redux, rxjs, redux-thunk, redux-observable

I'm trying to create an epic that will take an action, and then dispatch two different actions, with the second one delayed by two seconds. After a bunch of attempts, this was the best I could do:

```js
const succeedEpic = action$ =>
  action$.filter(action => action.type === 'FETCH_WILL_SUCCEED')
    .mapTo({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
    .merge(Observable.of({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' }).delay(2000))
```

Unfortunately, it seems that:

```js
Observable.of({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' }).delay(2000)
```

Is run immediately upon my app being loaded (rather than when an event comes down the parent stream). I noticed this because the `FETCH_SUCCESS` action is received by the reducer exactly two seconds after my app is loaded. I even attached a `console.log` to confirm this:

```js
const succeedEpic = action$ =>
  action$.filter(action => action.type === 'FETCH_WILL_SUCCEED')
    .mapTo({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
    .merge(Observable.of({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' })
           .do(() => console.log('this has begun'))
           .delay(2000)
          )
```

"this has begun" is logged to the console the moment the app is started.

I suspect this has something to do with how Redux-Observable automatically subscribes for you.

The desired behaviour is that I will:

1. Click a button that dispatches the `FETCH_WILL_SUCCEED` event.
2. Immediately, a `FETCH_REQUEST` event is dispatched.
3. Two seconds after that, a `FETCH_SUCCESS` event is dispatched.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I needed to wrap both of my events inside a `mergeMap`. Thanks to @dorus on the RxJS Gitter channel for this answer.

This is my working result:

```js
const succeedEpic = action$ =>
  action$.filter(action => action.type === 'FETCH_WILL_SUCCEED')
    .mergeMapTo(Observable.of({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
      .concat(Observable.of({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' })
        .delay(1000)))
```

`merge` should work as well in place of `concat`, but I thought `concat` makes better semantic sense.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant solution, but why not just use 2 epics and combine them?

The first one dispatches the fetch request:

```
const onFetchWillSucceed = action$ => action$.ofType('FETCH_WILL_SUCCEED')
  .mapTo({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
```

The second one waits 2 secs and dispatches the success:

```
const onFetchRequest = action$ => action$.ofType('FETCH_REQUEST')
  .delay(2000)
  .mapTo({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS' })
```

And in the end they are just combined into 1 epic

```
const both = combineEpics(onFetchWillSucceed, onFetchRequest)
```

Comment: That won't work because my next step is to create a "fetch will fail" epic that also dispatches FETCH_REQUEST, but the subsequent action is FETCH_FAIL instead of FETCH_SUCCESS.